# C# выделение контрола в Panel

Tags: c#, winforms, control-panel

Пример
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Control control;
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      main_panel.Controls.Add(new SecondPanel(control, 300, 100));
      main_panel.Controls.Add(new SecondPanel(control, 300, 200));
      main_panel.Controls.Add(new SecondPanel(control, 300, 300));
    }
  }
}
```

```html
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
  class SecondPanel : Panel
  {
    private Control control;
    public SecondPanel(Control control, int x, int y) {
      this.Location = new Point(x, y);
      this.control = control;
      this.Click += new EventHandler(click);
      this.BackColor = Color.Blue;
      this.Size = new Size(50, 50);
    }

    private void click(object sender, EventArgs e)  {
      this.BackColor = Color.Red;
      if(control != null) {
          control.BackColor = Color.Blue;
          control = this;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

В результате если кликать все закрашивается красным
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
а мне нужно чтобы предыдущая панель обратно ставала синей

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос больше кода. `this.control = this;` - ??

Comment: Изменил с кодом и примером

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужен отдельный объект со ссылкой на последнюю кликнутую панель.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
  class SecondPanelHolder
  {
    SecondPanel panel;
  }

  class SecondPanel : Panel
  {
    public SecondPanelHolder Holder { get; set; }

    public SecondPanel(SecondPanel holder, int x, int y) {
      this.Location = new Point(x, y);
      this.Holder = holder;
      this.Click += new EventHandler(click);
      this.BackColor = Color.Blue;
      this.Size = new Size(50, 50);
    }

    private void click(object sender, EventArgs e)  {
      if (Holder != null) {
        if (Holder.panel != null)
          Holder.panel.BackColor = Color.Blue;
        Holder.panel = this;
      }
      this.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
  }
}
```

Дадим этот объект всем панелям.

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    SecondPanelHolder holder = new SecondPanelHolder();

    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      main_panel.Controls.Add(new SecondPanel(holder, 300, 100));
      main_panel.Controls.Add(new SecondPanel(holder, 300, 200));
      main_panel.Controls.Add(new SecondPanel(holder, 300, 300));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Можна заменить SecondPanelHolder на просто SecondPanel?

Comment: @MikeWaters Нет. В том-то и дело, что нужен дополнительный слой (level of indirection) - объект, который не меняется, но содержит меняющуюся ссылку.

Comment: @MikeWaters Но его можно назвать `ControlHolder`, и держать в нем `Control control;`.